# How to have more font sizes in Squeak?

Tags: fonts, smalltalk, squeak, monospace

I installed the font `DejavuSansMono` which is `ttf` in Squeak. I want to use it in the *Transcript* and *CommandShell*.

*Note*: just download the ttf file then load it through the Squeak FileList app.

Now, if I select some text in *Transcript* then RightClick -> SetFont. I can change the font to `DejavuSansMono` but only to size : `{9, 12, 15, 24, 36 }`.

I would like to have other intermediate sizes. Is it possible? My knowledge of fonts is minimal, but I suppose it is, since in [this page](https://www.1001fonts.com/dejavu-sans-mono-font.html#waterfall) I see the sizes: `{10,14,18}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the size you want to have.

If I would like to have a font size `10`, I would do it the following way:

`(TextStyle named: #DejaVuSansMono) addNewFontSize: 10`

I presume what you get when you install a new font are the most common sizes.
You can check what sizes you have via:

`TextStyle fontArrayForStyle: #DejaVuSansMono`

you should get (after adding font size 10):

```
{TTCFont(DejaVuSansMono 9 Book) . TTCFont(DejaVuSansMono 10 Book) . TTCFont(DejaVuSansMono 12 Book) . TTCFont(DejaVuSansMono 15 Book) . TTCFont(DejaVuSansMono 24 Book) . TTCFont(DejaVuSansMono 36 Book)}
```

### Edit: How did I find it? (I'm not using Squeak on regular basis)

In the `TTCFontSet>>#familyName:pointSize:` you will find a (global) Dictionary `TextConstants`.

If you inspect the `TextConstants`, find `a TextStyle DejaVuSansMono` instance. When you inspect it you will see the details.  From there I thought to check a `TextStyle` class.  There I found `TextStyle>>#addNewFontSize:` which you can use to introduce a new size.

When you add the `#DejaVuSansMono` to Squeak you will get a *This font does not have a kerning table* message, which means that you will not get optimized specing between characters.  I recommnend reading some good source [what is kerning](https://www.figma.com/dictionary/kerning/) to know more.

Comment: Fantastic @tucan ! I was struggling with the default font since the first days in Squeak. When I am selecting Increase/Decrease Font Size I am getting font either too small or to large for my needs. Now I know this also can be tuned, so it goes behind the  Monospace. I add a picture to show what I got and probably illutrate the Kerning issue.

Comment: @NicolaMingotti I'm happy that it helped you.  I did not elaborate on the kerning as that was not the original quesiton.

Answer (score 1):

I followed @tucan directions and it all works great.

I add here a picture for completeness showing the difference I see between the default `Bitmap DejaVu Sans` and the `DejaVuSans` `ttf` I got from the Internet.

The Kerning issue can ben seen(?) if you watch closely at the "y" character in *TextStyle* word.

Also, I see that the letters "t" and "n" in general look worse in `DejaVuSans`, but this font can be resized at pleasure.

[image: Kerning Example]

Comment: Just comment on the screenshot.  In smalltalk you don't need to explicitly type the number sequence. You could do it the following "more" smalltalk way: `16 to: 20 do: [ :fontSize | 
 (TextStyle named: #DejaVuSans) addNewFontSize: fontSize
]`

Comment: Luckily that is something that I already know;) The shot is a bit criptic, it wants to convey the idea that I had to produce several manual attempts to find a `DejaVuSans` as large as the original `BitmapDejaVuSans-17`. Finally i landed at the dimension 20.5.

Comment: Well, with these comments it should be more clear for possible future readers. Also it illustrates the the TTF font DejaVuSans is not bad at all in Squeak. Consider I am running it under FreeBSD with Linux emulation. Having nice fonts does not come for free in this setup.